# How to create customised Rest endpoints in kogito quarkus

Tags: rest, drools, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, kogito

I am creating a kogito app with DRL files in it . It’s generating REST endpoints based on Rule names in DRL files. How can I change it as per my requirement ? e.g.

rule findStudents
When ///
Then ///

So endpoint will be -> http://localhost:8080/find-students
I want something like this-> http://localhost:8080/findAllStudents

Answer (score 1):

Currently each rule unit will generate a REST endpoint.

You can take a look at what's generating in `target/sources` and create your own REST endpoint. You will se the Rule Unit is injected and from then you can start interacting with it

Comment: Adding to Luca comment, you can take a look at this link to stop generating the default REST endpoints: https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#ref-kogito-runtime-properties_kogito-configuring

Also, for the next release (1.12), you can use our own (incubator) API: https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/main/dmn-incubation-api-quarkus to interact with the core engine.